# What is meant by Restricted Maintenance (Red Hat updates)?

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade

I need to install a [couple of patches](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:1203)...

More specifically `java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.191` however when performing the `yum update` command there are "No Packages marked for Update". Is this because according to the Red Hat website its under "Restricted Maintenance"?

I have never seen this (Restricted Maintenance) before; can someone please explain what it's all about?

Answer (score 1):

Some Red Hat product subscriptions purchased before December 2017 included Oracle Java SE, and will continue to receive support for it until the end of November 2018. Subscriptions purchased after December 2017 no longer include Oracle Java SE and can’t use it. As I understand it, this is what is meant in this case by “restricted maintenance“: it covers packages which are only available for a subset of subscriptions for a given product, with a time limit.

If you have access to Oracle Java SE, your subscriptions should have been updated for you. If that’s not the case, you should contact Red Hat technical support.

See [this knowledgebase article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3253281) for details.

(I’m only speaking for myself as always.)